# multiple mysql statements not executed via php (statement works via phpmyadmin)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

While creating a statistics program I'm keeping track how many aircraft visit an aerodrome per hour.

My script calculates the number of flights in the last hour and saves this to the database. my i keep getting mysql syntax error if I copy the statement in phpmyadmin it works

```
$date = 2013091713;
//$date = date('YmdH', mktime(date('H')));

$sql = '';
foreach ($aerodrome as $icao => $value) {
    $sql .= "INSERT INTO flightsperhour(date, aerodrome, inbound, outbound) 
             VALUES('". $date ."', '" . $icao . "' , " . (isset($value['inboud']) ? $value['inboud'] : 0)  . ", " . (isset($value['outbound']) ? $value['outbound'] : 0) . ");";
}
//INSERT INTO flightsperhour(date, aerodrome, inbound,outbound) VALUES('2013091713', 'EBBR' , 0, 1);
//INSERT INTO flightsperhour(date, aerodrome, inbound,outbound) VALUES('2013091713', 'ELLX' , 0, 1);
if(mysql_query($sql))
{

} else{
    die(mysql_error());
}
```

EDIT: Mysql error: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO flightsperhour(date, aerodrome, inbound, outbound) VALUES('2013' at line 2`

EDIT2: Fixed the single missing `'`

EDIT3: On request of the programming student a print_r of his solution

```
INSERT INTO flightsperhour(date, aerodrome, inbound, outbound) 
             VALUES('2013091713', 'EBBR' , '', '1'),
             VALUES('2013091713', 'ELLX' , '', '1')
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your 
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use 
near 'VALUES('2013091713', 'ELLX' , '', '1')' at line 3
```

Comment: Note: your code is open to [SQL injections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). If possible, use PHP's new mysqli library instead of the old mysql extension and take advantage of [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: Only use `VALUES ` once, (so `VALUES (..1st row..),(..2nd row...),(..3rd row..)`, **not** `VALUES (..1st row..),VALUES(..2nd row...),VALUES(..3rd row..)`, and remember you can get only _one_ statement in _one_ `mysql_query()`.

Comment: that last one fixed it :-) thanks Wrikken didn't know that mysql query function took only one statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing colon `'` between `$date`, and `$icao`.

Corrected code:

```
$date = 2013091713;
//$date = date('YmdH', mktime(date('H')));

$sql = '';
 $sql .= "INSERT INTO flightsperhour(date, aerodrome, inbound, outbound) ";
foreach ($aerodrome as $icao => $value) {
    $inbound = isset($value['inboud']) ? $value['inboud'] : 0;
    $outbound = isset($value['outbound']) ? $value['outbound'] : 0;
    $sql .= "
             VALUES('". $date ."', '" . $icao . "' , '" . $inboud  . "', '" . $outbound . "'),";
}

$sql = substr($sql, 0, strlen($sql)-1);
//INSERT INTO flightsperhour(date, aerodrome, inbound,outbound) VALUES('2013091713', 'EBBR' , 0, 1);
//INSERT INTO flightsperhour(date, aerodrome, inbound,outbound) VALUES('2013091713', 'ELLX' , 0, 1);
if(mysql_query($sql))
{

} else{
    die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: still the same with the fixed colon

Comment: using your code and an echo  statement I get `INSERT INTO flightsperhour(date, aerodrome, inbound, outbound) VALUES('2013091713', 'EBBR' , '', '1');INSERT INTO flightsperhour(date, aerodrome, inbound, outbound) VALUES('2013091713', 'ELLX' , '', '1');` which gives the exact same mysql error

Comment: your answer combined with Wrikken comment fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

You have not closed the single quote for the `$date` change this `'". $date ."` to `'". $date ."'`

```
$sql .= "INSERT INTO flightsperhour(date, aerodrome, inbound, outbound) 
             VALUES('". $date ."', '" . $icao . "' , " . (isset($value['inboud']) ? $value['inboud'] : 0)  . ", " . (isset($value['outbound']) ? $value['outbound'] : 0) . ");";
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you to use PDO https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php or MySQLi Extension because Php 5.5 wont be supporting MySQL extension any more

```
$date = 2013091713;
//$date = date('YmdH', mktime(date('H')));

$db_conn = new PDO('mysql:host=<host>;dbname=<database name>', '<username>', '<password>');


try{
$sql = $db_conn->prepare("INSERT INTO flightsperhour(date, aerodrome, inbound, outbound) VALUES (:date,:aerodrome,:inbound,:outbound)");

foreach ($aerodrome as $icao => $value) {
    $inbound = isset($value['inboud']) ? $value['inboud'] : 0;
    $outbound = isset($value['outbound']) ? $value['outbound'] : 0;
    $sql->execute(
            array(
                ":date" => $date,
                ":aerodrome" => $aerodrome,
                ":inbound" => $inbound,
                ":outbound" => $outbound
            )
    );
}
}
catch (PDOException $pe){
    print $pe->getMessage();
}
```